# Searching a primitive of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to resolve this exercice:
Determine the primitive $F$ of the function:
$f(x)=\frac{|x|+x+4}{(x^2+x+1)(x+2)}$, such that $F(1)=-1$, moreover specifies the widest range in which the primitive exists.

I tried to poceed in this way.

If $x\geq0$, we solve the integral $\int \frac{2}{x^2+x+1} dx = \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}atan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x+\frac{1}{2}))+c_1$.

If $x<0$, we solve the integral $\int \frac{4}{(x^2+x+1)(x+2)} dx = -\frac{2}{3}log(x^2+x+1)+\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}atan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x+\frac{1}{2}))+\frac{4}{3}log|x+2|+c_2 $.

To ensure the continuity in $0$,we compute that $c_2=c_1-\frac{4}{3}log(2)$. It is sufficent to impose that $F(1)=-1$ and we have $\bar{c_1}=-1-\frac{4\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$, so the primitive is:

$F(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}atan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x+\frac{1}{2}))+\bar{c_1}\quad \text{if} \;\;x\geq 0 \\ -\frac{2}{3}log(x^2+x+1)+\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}atan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x+\frac{1}{2}))+\frac{4}{3}log|x+2|+\bar{c_1}-\frac{4}{3}log(2)  \quad \text{if} \;\;x<0\end{cases}$

The widest range in which the primitive exists, seems to be $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{-2\}$. Is this reasoning correct?  Is there another approach which use the foundamental theorem of integral calculus?

Thank you.

Comment: In the second part I'd write $\log(x+2)$ instead of using the absolute value. Using $\log|x+2|$ enlarges the domain to $x\ne -2$ which is not correct

Comment: Thanks I agree, but at the same time I can't formalize the reason. If I use GeoGebra, the primitive exists in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{-2\}$.

Comment: Yet you wrote that the domain is $(2,+\infty)$ and this is a contradiction

Comment: Yes,the problem is that my intuition say this, for a question of convergence of the integral, but how we can formalize this? At the same time GeoGebra plot the primitive with the absolute value and this confused me.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't. It plots the primitive only for $x>-2$ and writes in the primitive formula $\log(x+2)$ and not abs value

Comment: Ok, which is the formal reason?

Comment: You could leave the abs value in your solution and correct the domain to $\mathbb{R}-\{-2\}$

Comment: So is the right domain  $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{-2\}?$